# C array with structs - cannot change variable

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Can anybody explain why

```
all_leds[0].pattern = 3;
```

and

```
all_leds[1].pattern = 4;
```

do nothing ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct Led
    {
      int pin;
      int pattern;
    };

    struct Led led_1 = {1, 1};
    struct Led led_2 = {2, 2};

    printf("%d\n", led_1.pattern);  // prints 1
    printf("%d\n", led_2.pattern);  // prints 2

    struct Led all_leds[2];
    all_leds[0] = led_1;
    all_leds[1] = led_2;

    printf("%d\n", led_1.pattern);  // prints 1
    printf("%d\n", led_2.pattern);  // prints 2

    all_leds[0].pattern = 3;
    all_leds[1].pattern = 4;

    printf("%d\n", led_1.pattern);    // prints 1 ????
    printf("%d\n", led_2.pattern);    // prints 2 ????

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are assigning to `all_leds[0].pattern` and printing `led_1.pattern` those are two different memory spaces...

Comment: The statements to something. It is just not what you expect. C has value semantics. Saying `a = b;` means `a` has the same value as `b`, it does not mean that they both refer to the same object.

Comment: so would it be helpfull to only store pointers to these structs in the array ?

Comment: @stepper_m yeah, that will lead to the effect you desire.

Answer (score 2):

`Led` is a value type (as are all types in C; it has no reference types like C++ has) so when you say `all_leds[0] = led_1;` you are *copying* the struct value in `led_1` into the first element of `all_leds`.  After this line, `all_leds[0]` and `led_1` remain separate values with no connection to each other.  Modifying one will not modify the other.

Instead, you can fill `all_leds` with pointers to the `Led` values.

```
struct Led * all_leds[2] = { &led_1, &led_2 };
// ...
all_leds[0]->pattern = 3;
all_leds[1]->pattern = 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are copying the values of `led_1` and `led_2` into your struct array. If you want them to be the same objects you should make your array an array of pointers to structs then you can update them by reference.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct Led
    {
      int pin;
      int pattern;
    };

    struct Led led_1 = {1, 1};
    struct Led led_2 = {2, 2};

    printf("%d\n", led_1.pattern);  // prints 1
    printf("%d\n", led_2.pattern);  // prints 2

    struct Led *all_leds[2];
    all_leds[0] = &led_1;
    all_leds[1] = &led_2;

    printf("%d\n", led_1.pattern);  // prints 1
    printf("%d\n", led_2.pattern);  // prints 2

    all_leds[0]->pattern = 3;
    all_leds[1]->pattern = 4;

    printf("%d\n", led_1.pattern);   
    printf("%d\n", led_2.pattern);    

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i figured out this one and it works as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct Led
    {
      int pin;
      int pattern;
    };

    struct Led led_1 = {1, 1};
    struct Led led_2 = {2, 2};
    printf("%d\n", led_1.pattern);
    printf("%d\n", led_2.pattern);

    struct Led * all_leds[2];
    all_leds[0] = &led_1;
    all_leds[1] = &led_2;

    printf("%d\n", led_1.pattern);
    printf("%d\n", led_2.pattern);

    all_leds[0] -> pattern = 3;
    all_leds[1] -> pattern = 4;
    printf("%d\n", led_1.pattern);
    printf("%d\n", led_2.pattern);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: many people working on this at the same time :) thank you all

Answer (score 0):

In these statements

```
printf("%d\n", led_1.pattern);    // prints 1 ????
printf("%d\n", led_2.pattern);    // prints 2 ????
```

you are ouputing data members of structures `led_1` and `led_2`. However in these statements

```
all_leds[0].pattern = 3;
all_leds[1].pattern = 4;
```

You changed elements of array `all_leds`. The array and object `led_1` and `Led_2` are different objects and occupy different areas of memory. So changing one object does not influence on other object.

Maybe you mean the following

```
printf("%d\n", all_leds[0].pattern);    // prints 1 ????
printf("%d\n", all_leds[1].pattern);    // prints 2 ????
```

Or you could define an array of pointers to structures. For example

```
struct Led *all_leds[2];
*all_leds[0] = &led_1;
*all_leds[1] = &led_2;
```

In this case after statements

```
all_leds[0]->pattern = 3;
all_leds[1]->pattern = 4;
```

and

```
printf("%d\n", led_1.pattern);    // prints 1 ????
printf("%d\n", led_2.pattern);    // prints 2 ????
```

you would get the expected result.